# Spring Boot JPA CrudRepository how to make optional search parameters

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

For the class below, where I am adding additional search methods to the repository, how do I make the search parameters optional in the findByFields method?
This method only has two parameters but consider a scenario with a lot more.

An example scenario is a search form page where there could be 10 to 20 search filters.
The user could use any combination of 0 to all search parameters.

Is there a way to make the fields optional in a sense that if a null value is supplied then that field will not be added as a query filter?

I know I could add logic inside the method to say if paramA and paramB have values then call a method for that combination and call another method for a different combination, but that would be a terrible solution in my opinion.

Any suggestions? 
Would be good to be able to do this without adding a manual query statement.

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import java.util.List;

public interface ReportMappingRepository extends CrudRepository<ReportMapping, Integer> {

    public ReportMapping findReportMappingByReportId(@Param("reportID") int reportId);

    public List<ReportMapping> findByFields(@Param("id")int id, @Param("reportID") int reportId);

}
```

Comment: You might want to look at Querydsl, which is supported by both Spring Data and Spring MVC.

Comment: Use JPA Specification for this case.

Comment: Thanks @Eklavya JPA Specficiation was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using JPA specification thanks to Eklavya for pointing me in the right direction.

Changed Repository to extend JpaSpecificationExecutor.

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

public interface ReportMappingRepository extends CrudRepository<ReportMapping, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<ReportMapping> {

}
```

Created search criteria and search operation classes then performed query like so.

```
    // Build up Search Criteria Specification
    // Id
    ReportMappingSpecification searchSpec = new ReportMappingSpecification();
    if (queryForm.getId() != null && queryForm.getId().length() > 0) {
        searchSpec.add(new SearchCriteria("id", queryForm.getId(), SearchOperation.EQUAL));
    }
    // reportId
    if (queryForm.getReportId() != null && queryForm.getReportId().length() > 0 && !queryForm.getReportId().equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
        searchSpec.add(new SearchCriteria("reportId", queryForm.getReportId(), SearchOperation.EQUAL));
    }

    // Run search
    reportMappingRepo.findAll(searchSpec).forEach(reportMappings::add);
```

Hope this helps someone else.